# Что происходит в рекурсивной функции?

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Имееться следующая функция на javascript:

```
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup(5));
```

Как понять рекурсию в ней?
Что происходит в коде по шагам чтобы понять рекурсию более понятнее? Что происходит при каждом n? Почему в массиве числа увеличиваються, а не уменьшаються?

Comment: _«Как понять рекурсию в ней? Что происходит в коде по шагам чтобы понять рекурсию более понятнее? Что происходит при каждом n?»_ - воспользоваться отладчиком и исследовать выполнение "по шагам".

Comment: откройте отладчик и детально по шагам просмотрите всё, что происходит. Ссылка на то, как пользоваться отладкой - см. выше в вопросе дубликате